# stopping the script by pressing the specific button (listen STDIN while script is dealing with it)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There is a script which interacts with the user by "press y / n" dialog (i.e. stdin is already in use). By pressing predefined keyboard button the main script should interrupt its work.

I tried to implement it two ways, with *read* and using *grep* (ah, and also tried using *stty* - stty -echo -icanon time 0 min 0, but all in all it didn`t work).

The problem with grep (grep -q ) is that the main thread goes in a loop with grep (which I looped in order to constantly check stdin), while I need the main script to move on, just listening STDIN for the specific key pressed.
With *read* it finally transformed into such a small piece:

```
breakByButton()
{
while ! [ "$z" = "11" ]
do
    read -t 1 -n 1 key

    if [[ $key = <desired key> ]]
    then
        echo -e "\n\e[31mStopped by user\e[0m"
        break
    fi
done
}
```

Of course, this function also works only where it was called. As a separate script in the background, as well as with grep, execution is interrupted after the first pressing Enter.
Now I'm thinking of the parallel process - the script and read, but haven`t got decisions yet.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Of course. And it is following: how to implement stopping the main script by pressing the specific button while the main script interacts with a user?

Comment: Wrote all the staff just to show where I'm now. The decision is near, I guess, but I don`t see it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is why there are interrupts.  If you want to interrupt a process that is otherwise using stdin, type ctrl-C.  This interrupts the process and, optionally, passes control to an interrupt handler.  For example, in this script `MyExit` functions as the interrupts handler.  If you run this script and type Ctrl-C, execution stops and your desired message will appear:

```
MyExit() {
    echo -e "\n\e[31mStopped by user\e[0m"
    exit
}    
trap MyExit INT

while true
do
    # do something important that captures stdin
    cat >/dev/null
done
```

In practice, `MyExit` should also do whatever is needed to clean up after script execution is interrupted.  This often includes, for example, deleting temporary files.

The key feature of this approach works even when *stdin is already in use*.  It does not require waiting until stdin is available.

Comment: trap EXIT means we display "Stopped by user" even for a normal termination. I think it's more relevant to trap INT here (you said ctrl+c in the description)

Comment: Thanks for this variant. Don`t know why didn`t find "trap" while googling.

Answer (score 2):

While havent abosolutely no idea what you **really** need, try the next demo (press `q` for exit)

```
trap 'stty sane;exit' 0 2

do_quit() {
    echo -e "Quit....\r" >&2
    return 1
}

do_something() {
    echo -e "Doing something after the key: $key\r"
}

inkey() {
    stty raw
    while :
    do
        read -t 1 -n 1 key
        case "$key" in
            q|Q) do_quit || exit ;;
            '') ;; #nothing
            *) do_something "$key" ;;
        esac
    done
}

#main
inkey
```

Comment: In my opinion "press a key to exit" is a behavior of the program. So I think your example is the right approach. My opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the variant. Though flexible and all in all interesting, I now choose a simpler variant (just "trap INT", as below) for this case (although firstly planned exit action as a part of program behavior, as truly written above). Saved for the future.